# Library for identifying lexical features of a string in Java

Tags: java, lexical

currently I need to find some special lexical characteristics of a string in Java such as

- Total number of characters
- Total number of alphabetic characters
- Total number of uppercase characters
- ....
  I wonder that is there a library can do that? It would be great to save coding time.

  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[google guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) can do that.

Have a look at the Strings module:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

Check out the *CharMatcher* on that site!

And after matching it, you just use the length() method of the remaining String.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such library. You'll have to write the 20 lines of code to do it yourself:

```
int length = s.length(); // get the length
int alphaCount;
for( int i=0; i<length; i ++ ) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    alphaCount += toInt( Character.isAlpha( c ) );
    ...
}
```

with

```
int toInt( boolean b ) { return b ? 1 : 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at:

- [`.length()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) property to get the amount of characters in a given String.
- [`.isLetter(Char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) to check if a character within a string is a letter.
- [`.isUpperCase(Char ch)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) to check if a character is upper case.

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain? It would be nice to have a force comments for downvotes... at least you know what others think you did wrong...